# Rebuild sphinx index in method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx

I have such method (i'm loading files to server):

```
def mymethod
****---****
flash[:notice] = "Price zagruzhen"
`rake ts:rebuild`
redirect_to admin_mainpage_path
end
```

and i need to update sphinx after some manipulations, but now i see that it's doesn't work, but why? if in console in folder i write rake ts:rebuild  all is ok, but in method something is bad.

could i do this without doing task? And when i must use task, how to use it?

Also i use nginx+passenger and rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use this method

```
Rails.application.load_tasks
Rake::Task['ts:rebuild'].invoke
```

Comment: hm, didn't help... index is still old, maybe something with ubuntu users?

Comment: no, just i see that for example for my article, price is not founded, but if i do rake ts:rebuild it's ok

Comment: hm no, i get RuntimeError (Don't know how to build task 'ts:rebuild'):
  app/controllers/admin/upload_controller.rb:15:in `update_sphinx_index'

Comment: but if i run: `rake ts:rebuild` it run, but seems that is rebuilding strange

Comment: Did you install thinking sphinx through bundler or system-wide?

Comment: gem with bundler, but sphinx wide, i get this even if i try ti run different rake, for example bundle

Comment: so, what do you think?

Comment: I've updated my answer, added one important, but missing line.

Comment: hm didn't understand, why on local machine index rebuild, but on server not((( maybe ubuntu auth trouble? how to solve then?

Comment: maybe you could help?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how underlying system could affect on rake tasks.